# How to eliminate oscilloscope channel DC bias

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement

When I set channel 1 as DC coupling, there is always -5.6v bias, even no cable is connected. Can someone tell me how can I eliminate this bias? Thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the make and model of the oscilloscope?

Comment: Looks like your scope needs re-calibrated.

Comment: @Platytude - From the photo, it's a Hantek DSO4102B.

Comment: @rdtsc After re-calibrated, the DC bias can be reduced to less than 1v. However, after around 10 minutes, the DC bias drifted back to 6v(not -5.6v before recalibrated).  Maybe I should return it to the manufacturer to repair it.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I had trouble reading the blue text on the black background

Comment: @RossLee - "*after around 10 minutes, the DC bias drifted back to 6v*" **It's faulty.** :-( There shouldn't be that sort of drift. || If you're going to repair it yourself, have the schematics, the repair skills, and have specific questions, then those questions *might* be deemed as on-topic here. I suspect anything else would be deemed as off-topic.

Comment: You can easily fix this in 2 steps with a small rectangular piece of plastic and a circular container.  1.  Place Hantek scope in circular container.  2. Go to your favorite equipment retailer and give them the numbers on the rectangular plastic in exchange for a Tektronix, Keysight or LeCroy scope.  (In all seriousness it sounds broken and in need of repair.)

Comment: There may be a calibrate option deep in a menu.  Check in the utility menu tree